# How to keep breakpoints on refresh of browser?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

I tried enabling preserve log option in chrome devtool settings, Still breakpoints are going off when i refresh the page.

I dont want to put debugger; all the time.

Comment: Keep `Developer Tools` open and `reload`.. `Preserve logs` and `Debugger` are not related with each other..

Comment: I'd also consider running firefox with firebug. It saves all breakpoints until they've been taken off (though remember to turn them off if you don't want to be left wondering why your codes stopped....)

Comment: Chrome should remember your breakpoints unless your source has changed considerably in between loads. Can you please share a page where this  issue reproduces for  you? Using Dev Channel here and it is working as expected.

Comment: Which Chrome version is this related to? Your title says "keep" which implies they're gone, your texts says they "are going off". What exactly happens? I second Garbee, they should be preserved during refresh, even on browser restart. Note the thick, flag-like arrow next to the "round" pause button - it can toggle all break points (or whether to break or not at all).